# return pointers from function. Value not updated for one pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I have tried to obtain 2 pointers from a function and print it in main. the vague thing is one pointer seems to have recovered its values, while the other hasn't. And both the pointers, have the correct value inside the calling function, just before returning as well. Please tell me if you can identify any programmatic error that is preventing me from getting the right answer.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    using namespace std;
    double* readctrls()
    {
         fstream inputs;
         inputs.open("input_coods.txt");
         int nol = 0,i = 0;
         string line,temp,subtemptrans,subtemprots;
         while(getline(inputs,line))
         {
                ++nol;
         }
//      cout<<nol<<endl;
        inputs.close();
        inputs.open("input_coods.txt");
        string *lines = new (nothrow) string[nol];
        double* trans = new double[nol];
        double* rots = new double[nol];
        trans[0] =float(nol);
        for(int i = 0; i<nol ; i++)
        {
                getline(inputs,lines[i]);
        //      cout<<lines[i]<<endl;
                temp = lines[i];
//              cout<<temp<<endl;
                for(int j = 0; j<temp.length() ; j++)
                {
                        if(temp.at(j) == ' ')
                        {
                                subtemptrans = temp.substr(0,j);
                                subtemprots = temp.substr(j+1,temp.length()-j);
        //                      cout<<subtemprots<<endl;
                                *(trans+i+1) = ::atof(subtemptrans.c_str());
                                *(rots+i) = float(atoi(subtemprots.c_str()));
                        //      cout<<rots[i]<<endl;
                        }
                }
        }                       
        inputs.close();         
//      cout<<rots[2]<<endl;    
        return(rots,trans);                                    
}                               

int main()                              
{                               
        double *trans,*rots;                                   
        (rots,trans) = readctrls();                            
//      cout<<sizeof(trans)<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<trans[0];i++)
        {                                                      
                cout<<*(trans+i)<<endl;
                cout<<*(rots+i)<<endl;
        }                                                      
}
```

The value of Trans is written fine in the memory and is perfectly retained from the main(). But the rots is giving garbage values of the order (e^-42). Please help me here.

Comment: I *know* there *must* be a specific reason you're returning `(rots,trans)` (which essentially throws out `rots` and just returns `trans`). But for the life of me I can't understand *why*. And I guess the memory leaks are a bonus? But the real question is, with `std::vector<double>` entirely at you're disposal, why are you dynamically allocating *anything* by hand in the first place? You would likely be *shocked* how much of this code goes away using stream extractions and standard lib containers.

Comment: I'm more interested in why did you make **assumptions.** If you don't know the language yet, that's OK, but if you don't read the RTFM, that's not OK at all.

Comment: Thanks for ur inputs. I understand that my knowledge in C++ is not as good as urs. Sorry for not being as adept as you people. But am trying here, so I requested a help. My apologies if it irritated you to c something so dumb. @WhozCraig I want both the values, so I returned it, but now I understand return doesn't work like that. learned something from this, thanks. I will look into vector and see how I can modify this code based on how it works. Thanks for your inputs again.

Comment: @H2CO3 I did not understand wat you meant by assumptions. Could you please elaborate. Apologies for asking.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan You **thought** that `return x, y` returned a pair of values: x and y. I don't know why did you think it. Well, I know. You **assumed** it did, and despite having never worked with this language construct before, you didn't fire up a C++ manual in order to search for the syntax and semantics of this operator.

Comment: @H2CO3 I understand. I will make sure to do everything and solve by myself before asking here for help. Thanks :).

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Okay, thanks, good luck for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**C++ is neither Python nor Lua.**

You can't return multiple values from a function.

```
return rots, trans;
```

This is the comma operator - evaluates its operands and yields the last (rightmost) one.

```
(rots, trans) = readctrls();
```

Likewise, this assigns to `trans` only, `rots` will be uninitialized.

Solution: you can either return a struct containing the two pointers, or pass them by reference, or whatever...

```
struct Foo {
    double *rots;
    double *trans;
};

Foo readctrls()
{
    // ...

    Foo r;
    r.rots = rots;
    r.trans = trans;
    return r;
}
```

or:

```
void readctrls(double *&r, double *&t)
{
    // ...

    r = rots;
    t = trans;
}
```

---

Other remarks:

1. Don't use raw arrays. `std::vector<T>` is generally preferred over `T *` in C++.
2. It's **super wasteful** to read the entire file just in order to count the lines, then read it once again to actually parse its contents. If you used an `std::vector<double>`, you could just `vector.push_back(some_double);` as you go along the lines, so you wouldn't have to walk through the file twice (you know, I/O is expensive, especially if the file is large).
3. You never `delete` the pointers that you allocate using `new` - here your program leaks memory.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this answer! got a lotta inputs from this. Thanks for your patience as well .